# Nested one to many relationships in Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, eloquent

Let's say I have three models with this relationsship

**USER**
*hasMany* (app/organisation)

**ORGANISATION**
*hasMany* (app/order)

**ORDER**

For one level I could just go
**user->organisations()->get()**

And get all the organisations tied to the user. But every organisation also have 0..many ORDER entities. So I want to do this:

**user->organisations()->orders()->get()**

To get a list of all the orders from all the organisations from a certain user. Is that possible this way?

Comment: If you try it you'll see that it is possible this way. It's also possible to pre-load them via `\User::with(["organisations", "organisations.orders"])->find()`

Comment: You can use `hasManyThrough()` here.https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: @Gayan Thank you. That solved it. write it as an answer if you want, then I can check it as correct.

Comment: @Christoffer I posted the answer, Glad you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can simply do is implement [hasManyThrough()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship on `User` model.

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, organisation::class);
}
```

then you can query like,

```
$user->orders()->get();
```